# How can I generate files of the sonar analysis as part of the build to be able to process those files?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, elastic-stack

I have set up a CI project with Eclipse, Jenkis, Git, Maven, Sonar and Nexus.The idea is that files are generated from the sonar analysis as part of the build to be able to process those files and send them to Elasticsearch. The problem is that I do not know how I can dump that data that I see through SonarQube to local files and send those logs to kibana

Comment: Why would you like to send SonarQube generated parts to a an Elastic search ? Why not using an SonarQube Server instance which makes more sense?

Comment: You're right, but I want to create specific Dashboards from different sources. I need to get that data and then pass it to JSON.

Comment: You need go into the sonar-maven-plugin ......See SonarQube pages...

Comment: Yes, I have been there all morning, but without success :`(

Answer (score 0):

The best way to access such data, if you need them for further processing, would be to use SonarQube's web api. You can check the doc on your SQ instance or you can use this public instance as a reference https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api

Comment: I wanted to try some Web API but it does not work. I'm working in local ... that's the reason why the page I'm looking for does not exist?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by working local, the web api is available on every SonarQube instance. Can you describe bit more what exactly you tried and how?

Comment: For example, if I write the uri: http://localhost:9000/web_api/api/ce/task, don´t give me  Compute Engine task details such as type, status, duration and associated component.

Comment: how are you invoking the request? what error code do you receive? are you are providing authentication info as part of the request?

Comment: Being honest I do not know very well what I'm doing. I simply chose a WEB API (localhost: 9000 / web_api / api / ce / task) to see what results it gave me, but it returns the same content as https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/ce/ task I think I'll keep trying for Maven ...

Comment: This has solved my problem: https://github.com/lequal/sonar-cnes-report